# split a multifasta file into different files with new headers

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

Input file: `131751_pphA.fasta`

```
>ID:NDNDCOEC_02118 |[Genus species]|strain|PANS_1_2_annot.gbk|pphA|855|NODE_3_length_422941_cov_112.146787422941(422941):170566-171420:1 ^^ Genus species strain strain.|neighbours:ID:NDNDCOEC_02117(1),ID:NDNDCOEC_02119(1)|neighbour_genes:hypothetical protein,ntaA| | aligned:1-284 (284)
MIKKLIAEKGTLIFIEAHNPLSALIASKAEQTNSEGRIVKFDGIWSSSLTDSASRGIPDNETLALSSRLENIADIRNVTDMPIIMDADTGGKPEHFSYYVKRMINNGVNGVIIEDKTGLKKNSLFGTEVEQTLADINDFSEKIKRGKSAVYIDDFMIIARLESLIAGFDVEHALERADAYVEAGADGIMIHSCKKTPDEVFLFSTKFRKKYPSVPLICVPTTYSATSNRELSEAGFNVIIYANHMLRAAYKAMENVSKEILRYGRTAEIEKSCMSVKEIISLIP
>ID:KJDCINFB_03194 |[Genus species]|strain|PNA_1_5_annot.gbk|pphA|855|NODE_5_length_527105_cov_93.286545527105(527105):274765-275619:1 ^^ Genus species strain strain.|neighbours:ID:KJDCINFB_03193(1),ID:KJDCINFB_03195(1)|neighbour_genes:hypothetical protein,ntaA| | aligned:1-284 (284)
MIKKLIAEKGTLIFIEAHNPLSALIASKAEQTNSEGRIVKFDGIWSSSLTDSASRGIPDNETLALSSRLENIADIRNVTDMPIIMDADTGGKPEHFSYYVKRMINNGVNGVIIEDKTGLKKNSLFGTEVEQTLADINDFSEKIKRGKSAVYIDDFMIIARLESLIAGFDVEHALERADAYVEAGADGIMIHSCKKTPDEVFLFSTKFRKKYPSVPLICVPTTYSATSNRELSEAGFNVIIYANHMLRAAYKAMENVSKEILRYGRTAEIEKSCMSVKEIISLIP
>ID:LBFHNJKP_02554 |[Genus species]|strain|PANS_1_6_annot.gbk|pphA|855|NODE_4_length_527158_cov_95.108790527158(527158):251540-252394:-1 ^^ Genus species strain strain.|neighbours:ID:LBFHNJKP_02553(-1),ID:LBFHNJKP_02555(-1)|neighbour_genes:ntaA,hypothetical protein| | aligned:1-284 (284)
MIKKLIAEKGTLIFIEAHNPLSALIASKAEQTNSEGRIVKFDGIWSSSLTDSASRGIPDNETLALSSRLENIADIRNVTDMPIIMDADTGGKPEHFSYYVKRMINNGVNGVIIEDKTGLKKNSLFGTEVEQTLADINDFSEKIKRGKSAVYIDDFMIIARLESLIAGFDVEHALERADAYVEAGADGIMIHSCKKTPDEVFLFSTKFRKKYPSVPLICVPTTYSATSNRELSEAGFNVIIYANHMLRAAYKAMENVSKEILRYGRTAEIEKSCMSVKEIISLIP
>ID:GPMHBDBL_03046 |[Genus species]|strain|PNA_200_2_annot.gbk|pphA_2|855|NODE_4_length_530984_cov_86.347264530984(530984):275036-275890:1 ^^ Genus species strain strain.|neighbours:ID:GPMHBDBL_03045(1),ID:GPMHBDBL_03047(1)|neighbour_genes:hypothetical protein,ntaA| | aligned:1-284 (284)
MIKKLIAEKGTLIFIEAHNPLSALIASKAEQTNSEGRIVKFDGIWSSSLTDSASRGIPDNETLALSSRLENIADIRNVTDMPIIMDADTGGKPEHFSYYVKRMINNGVNGVIIEDKTGLKKNSLFGTEVEQTLADINDFSEKIKRGKSAVYIDDFMIIARLESLIAGFDVEHALERADAYVEAGADGIMIHSCKKTPDEVFLFSTKFRKKYPSVPLICVPTTYSATSNRELSEAGFNVIIYANHMLRAAYKAMENVSKEILRYGRTAEIEKSCMSVKEIISLIP
```

---

Desired output: four separate output files:

`PANS_1_2_pphA.fasta`

```
>PANS_1_2_pphA
MIKKLIAEKGTLIFIEAHNPLSALIASKAEQTNSEGRIVKFDGIWSSSLTDSASRGIPDNETLALSSRLENIADIRNVTDMPIIMDADTGGKPEHFSYYVKRMINNGVNGVIIEDKTGLKKNSLFGTEVEQTLADINDFSEKIKRGKSAVYIDDFMIIARLESLIAGFDVEHALERADAYVEAGADGIMIHSCKKTPDEVFLFSTKFRKKYPSVPLICVPTTYSATSNRELSEAGFNVIIYANHMLRAAYKAMENVSKEILRYGRTAEIEKSCMSVKEIISLIP
```

`PNA_1_5_pphA.fasta`

```
>PNA_1_5_pphA
MIKKLIAEKGTLIFIEAHNPLSALIASKAEQTNSEGRIVKFDGIWSSSLTDSASRGIPDNETLALSSRLENIADIRNVTDMPIIMDADTGGKPEHFSYYVKRMINNGVNGVIIEDKTGLKKNSLFGTEVEQTLADINDFSEKIKRGKSAVYIDDFMIIARLESLIAGFDVEHALERADAYVEAGADGIMIHSCKKTPDEVFLFSTKFRKKYPSVPLICVPTTYSATSNRELSEAGFNVIIYANHMLRAAYKAMENVSKEILRYGRTAEIEKSCMSVKEIISLIP
```

`PANS_1_6_pphA.fasta`

```
>PANS_1_6_pphA
MIKKLIAEKGTLIFIEAHNPLSALIASKAEQTNSEGRIVKFDGIWSSSLTDSASRGIPDNETLALSSRLENIADIRNVTDMPIIMDADTGGKPEHFSYYVKRMINNGVNGVIIEDKTGLKKNSLFGTEVEQTLADINDFSEKIKRGKSAVYIDDFMIIARLESLIAGFDVEHALERADAYVEAGADGIMIHSCKKTPDEVFLFSTKFRKKYPSVPLICVPTTYSATSNRELSEAGFNVIIYANHMLRAAYKAMENVSKEILRYGRTAEIEKSCMSVKEIISLIP
```

`PNA_200_2_pphA_2.fasta`

```
>PNA_200_2_pphA_2
MIKKLIAEKGTLIFIEAHNPLSALIASKAEQTNSEGRIVKFDGIWSSSLTDSASRGIPDNETLALSSRLENIADIRNVTDMPIIMDADTGGKPEHFSYYVKRMINNGVNGVIIEDKTGLKKNSLFGTEVEQTLADINDFSEKIKRGKSAVYIDDFMIIARLESLIAGFDVEHALERADAYVEAGADGIMIHSCKKTPDEVFLFSTKFRKKYPSVPLICVPTTYSATSNRELSEAGFNVIIYANHMLRAAYKAMENVSKEILRYGRTAEIEKSCMSVKEIISLIP
```

The multifasta input file (`131751_pphA.fasta`) contains four fasta sequences with headers. I want four output files that are individual fasta sequences with their names and headers named as per the strain as mentioned above. For example, one of headers in the input fasta contains the strain information as `|strain|PANS_1_2_annot.gbk|pphA|`. The output file should have its name as
`PANS_1_2_pphA.fasta` and its header as `>PANS_1_2_pphA`.

Similarly the other output files as
`PNA_1_5_pphA.fasta` with header `>PNA_1_5_pphA`
`PANS_1_6_pphA.fasta` with header `>PANS_1_6_pphA`
`PNA_200_2_pphA_2.fasta` with header `>PNA_200_2_pphA_2`

Tried the following code:

```
awk -F "|" '/^>/ {close(F); ID=$1; gsub("^>", "", ID); F=ID".fasta"} {print >> F}' 123764_pphA.fasta
```

Resulting in fasta output files with following names:

```
ID:BKKCPFME_02840 .fasta  ID:EKPOMJAO_03222 .fasta  ID:HEIIBHGJ_01315 .fasta  ID:KBMOKBJB_03162 .fasta  ID:LECGKDGM_03166 .fasta
```

Comment: please note that only one answer you can chose as accepted answer not multiple answers, so when you chose an answer as accepted you confirm that your question is resolved by that answer you marked as accepted. I'm writing this because you changed the accepted answer almost on your all questions recently.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F'|' '
    NR%2{ close(fileName); hdr=$4 $5; sub("annot.gbk", "", hdr); fileName=hdr".fasta";
          print ">"hdr >fileName; next; };
        { print >fileName; }' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

A non `awk` solution, assuming, given the example, that the file must be splited every 2 lines:

```bsh
# split the file every 2 lines and save in files prefixed FOO.
split -l2 131751_pphA.fasta FOO.

# loop over the files
for f in FOO.*; do 
  # `awk` and `sed` to get the pattern to use as file name and first line, i.e "PANS_1_2_pphA"
  n=$(awk -F'|' '{ print $4$5 }' "$f" | \
    sed 's/annot\.gbk//')

  # copy the 2nd line of the file into a new file named as pattern+.fasta
  sed -n 2p "$f" > "$n.fasta"

  # add the pattern in the created file
  sed -i "1i>\\$n" "$n.fasta"

  # remove the splited files
  rm "$f"
done
```

---

```
$ cat PANS_1_2_pphA.fasta 
PANS_1_2_pphA
MIKKLIAEKGTLIFIEAHNPLSALIASKAEQTNSEGRIVKFDGIWSSSLTDSASRGIPDNETLALSSRLENIADIRNVTDMPIIMDADTGGKPEHFSYYVKRMINNGVNGVIIEDKTGLKKNSLFGTEVEQTLADINDFSEKIKRGKSAVYIDDFMIIARLESLIAGFDVEHALERADAYVEAGADGIMIHSCKKTPDEVFLFSTKFRKKYPSVPLICVPTTYSATSNRELSEAGFNVIIYANHMLRAAYKAMENVSKEILRYGRTAEIEKSCMSVKEIISLIP
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
awk -F '|' '
    /^>/ {
        close(out)
        head = $4
        sub("_[^_]*$","_" $5, head)
        $0 = ">" head
        out = head ".fasta"
    } { print >out }' 131751_pphA.fasta
```

This is *similar* to [αғsнιη's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/632549/116858) but allows each sequence to be more than one line (which is possible in a generic FastA file).

I'm also trimming the header name a bit differently, trimming off anything after the last `_` in `.gbk` filename (?) that is found in the fourth `|`-delimited field on the FastA header line, and adding  the fifth field.